# Find broken links in CSS & JS in Vidual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am importing a lot of CSS & JS into my app and updating the links as I go.  Is there any code inspection possible that will highlight these broken links to make sure I haven't missed any and to save me going through every file?

I know in other IDE's this is a standard thing so I am guessing there should be something in VS but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that it's not possible in pure Visual Studio.

But there is one trick which you can do using ReSharper which might help you and solve your problem. Take a look below:

[image]

What is more - you can configure ReSharper to show those "Path errors" not as warning but as errors! Then you will be able to show those during compilation.

1. Click "ReSharper" in the Visual Studio top menu, then "Options..."
2. There will be search box in the left upper corner of the "Options" window
3. Type "Path error" and hit return
4. Change all of the "Warning" to "Error"

[image]

Comment: Guess I'll have to save my pocket money for a resharper license :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of sites/tools as listed [here](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/4-simple-tools-to-find-broken-links-in.html) that will check anchor links, css links, image links, JavaScript links, etc:

- [W3C Link Checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink)
- [Xenu's Link Slueth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html)
- [Link Checker FireFox AddOn](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/linkchecker/)
- [Dead Link Checker](http://www.dead-link-checker.com/en/)

I have only ever used the W3C checker which seems to work quite well.

Comment: I mean as a code inspection.  Those tools don't work inside Visual Studio IDE.  In PHPStorm I can set a code inspection and it will show me all broken links in project.  Seems strange Visual Studio doesn't have this seeing as it costs 6x the price.

Comment: Maybe this extension might help you: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28650fe9-f41e-4db9-9d61-4e3f59c85b5e